# Powershell command line logs - what is 'prompt'

Tags: powershell, logging

Pulling command line logs for powershell we added the variables

```
#$LogCommandHealthEvent = $true
#$LogCommandLifeCycleEvent = $true
```

and it works great but what is 'prompt'??

```
Time                 Event Command    
----                 ----- -------    
5/27/2016 1:38:31 PM   501 prompt     
5/27/2016 1:38:31 PM   500 prompt     
5/27/2016 1:38:31 PM   501 get-process
5/27/2016 1:38:31 PM   500 get-process
5/27/2016 1:38:29 PM   501 prompt     
5/27/2016 1:38:29 PM   500 prompt     
5/27/2016 1:38:29 PM   501 ipconfig
```

this does appear in the eventdata in the logs -
faa69d45087e PipelineId=608 CommandName=prompt CommandType=Function ScriptName= CommandPath= CommandLine=prompt

Comment: `prompt` is function which responsible for generating prompt.

Comment: So we want to monitor when anyone(esp bad guys) run commands from powershell.  Is the prompt function called every single time a command is run from the command line?

Comment: It's called every single time PowerShell displays `PS C:\> ` or whatever the path is.  It's the function that actually does that during interactive sessions.  Otherwise, you'd just get a blinking cursor.  You can see what it does by looking at `Get-Item Function:\prompt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition`.

Comment: It's also the method you can define to customize your prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [About_Prompts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847739.aspx)

```
    The Prompt function determines the appearance of the Windows PowerShell 
    prompt. Windows PowerShell comes with a built-in Prompt function, but
    you can override it by defining your own Prompt function.

...

BUILT-IN PROMPT
    Windows PowerShell includes a built-in prompt function. 

    In Windows PowerShell 3.0, the built-in prompt function is:
```

```ps1
    function prompt
    {
        "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
    }
```

Additional details:

1. The prompt function is called each time the prompt is displayed to refresh any details on the prompt (such as the path.)